# What's the proper way to install rails after cloning from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cloned rails 4 from github and want to install rails from the local repo.  What's the best way to do the installation?  I ran install.rb starting from a fresh gemset but it failed because of missing gems.  Anyone know a post that walks through this?  Should I do the install from the remote github repo first and then run the install.rb file?

Also, just want to be clear here.  I am not trying to just install using gem install or using :git in my gem file.  Please do not put those instructions in your comments.  I absolutely want to install from a local clone, as a first step toward fixing Rails when I encounter bugs not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Bundle the local gem.

```
gem "rails", :path => "~/your/rails/checkout"
gem "activerecord", :path => "~/your/rails/checkout"

etc...
```

Comment: That defines what is in my gemfile, right? How do I get an initial rails going to get to that point?  gem install rails --source "~/your/rails/checkout"?  Maybe install rails 3.2 using gem and then modify the gemfile?

Comment: Do I have to build the local gem first?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, the gem building is only for redistribution, using a git checkout (made by bundler with the :git option, or your own) just skips the gem unpacking.

Comment: And you could install edge rails as a gem, use its generators to bootstrap your application, then declare your local path in bundler to use the local code in your app.

Comment: I think the key missing step is bootstrapping the app.  I started from a clean gemset and most times you would not.  The install ruby script looks like it was intended to do that for you by installing gems that come in the git clone.  That fails because there are some dependencies that don't exist yet (activerecord-deprecated_finders,journey).  I am doing each gem one-by-one resolving the dependencies and that seems to be working.  Overall, is this making sense?